# Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu freezes when dragging file to another directory

Tags: ubuntu, crash, file

I have some files I downloaded onto my desktop but when I try to drag them to another directory in the file manager, the pi freezes and I have to unplug and reboot it. This has happened 3 times already so I don't think it's a coincidence, but why does moving the files cause this and what can I do to avoid freezing my pi when I want to move files?

Comment: Size of the files?

Comment: they are between 5 and 15 megabytes each, about 4 of them

Comment: After at least 3 hard reboots I bet on filesystem errors being the reason.